# How to monitor progress of ssh file transfer and output to a log file

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I'm writing a bash script to periodically transfer data to a remote system.  I have a local command that generates a stream, and a remote command that consumes it, so I'm doing something like this:

```
generate_data | ssh remoteserver.example.com consume_data
```

(Where I have ssh keys set up so I can do this non-interactively.)  This works fine.  However, since this will be an automated process (running as a cron job) and may sometimes be transferring large amounts of data on limited bandwidth, I'd like to be able place periodic progress updates in my log file.  I had thought to use `pv` (pipe viewer) for this, and this is the best I could come up with:

```
generate_data | pv -fb | ssh remoteserver.example.com consume_data
```

Again, it works... **but** pv was really written with terminal output in mind, so I end up with a mess in the log that looks like

```
2.06MB^M2.19MB^M2.37MB^M 2.5MB^M2.62MB^M2.87MB^M3MB^M3.12MB^M3.37MB
```

I'd prefer log messages along the lines of

```
<timestamp> 2.04MB transferred...
<timestamp> 3.08MB transferred...
```

If anybody has any clever ideas of how to do this, either with different arguments to `pv` or via some other mechanism, I'd be grateful.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers so far.  Of course there are a lot of possible home-brewed solutions; I was hoping to find something that would work "out of the box."  (Not that I'm ruling out home-brewed; it may be the easiest thing in the end.  Since `pv` already does 98% of what I need, I'd prefer not to re-invent it.)

***PostScript:*** Here's the line I ended up using, in hopes it might help someone else at some point.

```
{ generate_data | pv -fbt -i 60 2>&3 | ssh remoteserver consume_data } 3>&1 | awk -vRS='\r' '{print $1 " transferred in " $2; fflush();}' >> logfile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with `pv`, you could postprocess its output a little. At a minimum, turn the CRs into LFs.

```
{ generate_data | pv -bft 2>&3 | consume_data >/dev/null; } 3>&1 | tr '\015' '\012'
```

Use awk for fancier processing.

```
{ generate_data | pv -bft 2>&3 | consume_data >/dev/null; } 3>&1 |
awk -vRS='\r' '{print $2, $1 " transferred"}'
```

Do however keep in mind that the standard text processing utilities only flush their output at the end of each line if they're printing to a terminal. So if you pipe `pv` to some other utility whose output goes to a pipe or file, there will be a non-negligible delay due to buffering. If you have GNU awk or some other implementation that has the `fflush` function (it's common but not standard), make it flush its output on every line:

```
{ generate_data | pv -bft 2>&3 | consume_data >/dev/null; } 3>&1 |
awk -vRS='\r' '{print $2, $1 " transferred"; fflush()}'
```

Comment: This is certainly the "scriptiest" approach, and your bash-fu is enviable.  (One change; you've conflated the decimal and octal values for CR and NL.  Should be `tr '\015' '\012'`--and then each output line is flushed as it's written.)

Comment: Ah, never mind, I see what you mean about the output flushing now. Hm.

Comment: Well, it turns out my awk has a `fflush()` function that takes care of that problem.  (Not sure that's actually part of POSIX, but whatever).  Problem solved!

Comment: @eaj: Right, take large values of 10 and 13. `fflush()` is not POSIX but fairly common (even OpenBSD has it).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small ruby script that I believe does what you want.  With the overhead of ruby, I only get about 1MB per second copying a file to the local filesystem, but you mentioned the pipes will have limited bandwidth so this may be OK.  I pulled the number_to_human_size function from rails (actionview).

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby                                                                                                                           
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'

# File vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 87                                                          
def number_to_human_size(size)
  case
    when size < 1.kilobyte: '%d Bytes' % size
    when size < 1.megabyte: '%.1f KB'  % (size / 1.0.kilobyte)
    when size < 1.gigabyte: '%.1f MB'  % (size / 1.0.megabyte)
    when size < 1.terabyte: '%.1f GB'  % (size / 1.0.gigabyte)
    else                    '%.1f TB'  % (size / 1.0.terabyte)
  end.sub('.0', '')
rescue
  nil
end

UPDATE_FREQ = 2
count = 0
time1 = Time.now

while (!STDIN.eof?)
  b = STDIN.getc
  count += 1
  print b.chr
  time2 = Time.now
  if time2 - time1 > UPDATE_FREQ
    time1 = time2
    STDERR.puts "#{time2} #{number_to_human_size(count)} transferred..."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  If I end up going down this sort of road, I'll probably do it in C.  Just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: My pleasure.  C would definitely be faster, especially with some buffering.  Another possibility would be to add a switch to pv so it doesn't try to pretty print the output and instead just prints text normally.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at bar: http://clpbar.sourceforge.net/

> Bar is a simple tool to copy a stream
>   of data and print a display for the
>   user on stderr showing (a) the amount
>   of data passed, (b) the throughput of
>   the data transfer, and (c) the
>   transfer time, or, if the total size
>   of the data stream is known, the
>   estimated time remaining, what
>   percentage of the data transfer has
>   been completed, and a progress bar.
>
> Bar was originally written for the
>   purpose of estimating the amount of
>   time needed to transfer large amounts
>   (many, many gigabytes) of data across
>   a network. (Usually in an SSH/tar
>   pipe.)

Comment: I'll check it out, although at first glance it looks like it (like `pv`) is geared toward terminal output, with cursor control characters and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Source code is at http://code.google.com/p/pipeviewer/source/checkout  so you can edit some C and use PV!

EDIT:
Yeah getting the source then editing line 578 of display.c where it has this code:

```
    display = pv__format(&state, esec, sl, tot);
if (display == NULL)
    return;

if (opts->numeric) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, display, strlen(display)); /* RATS: ignore */
} else if (opts->cursor) {
    pv_crs_update(opts, display);
} else {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, display, strlen(display)); /* RATS: ignore */
    write(STDERR_FILENO, "\r", 1);
}
```

you can change "\r" to "\n" and recompile. This may get you some more useful output, by having it on a new line each time. And you could try reformatting that entire output string too if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a small perl program what copy STDIN into STDOUT and print his progress to STDERR?

Answer (score 0):

Check out SSHLog: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a daemon that monitors SSH logins as well as user activity. All user activity (everything that happens on the shell) is passively recorded and available to point to outputs.

It monitors SCP file transfers as well.  You can configure it to listen to file transfer events and write just those events to a log file.